# Defining members of a struct within a namespace

Tags: c++, opengl, freetype

I'm using NeHe's tutorial on FreeType and OpenGL, and I'm having a problem defining members of 
struct font_data within namespace freetype. It doesn't recognize font_data as a struct when I define its members in the namespace.

CE_Text.h:

```
#ifndef CE_TEXT
#define CE_TEXT

#include <Common/Headers.h>

/////////////////// MAJOR CREDIT TO NeHe FOR HIS TUTORIAL ON FREETPYE ///////////////////

///Wrap everything in a namespace, that we can use common
///function names like "print" without worrying about
///overlapping with anyone else's code.
namespace freetype {

    //Inside of this namespace, give ourselves the ability
    //to write just "vector" instead of "std::vector"
    using std::vector;

    //Ditto for string.
    using std::string;

    //This holds all of the information related to any
    //freetype font that we want to create.  
    struct font_data{
        float h;            ///< Holds the height of the font.
        GLuint * textures;  ///< Holds the texture id's 
        GLuint list_base;   ///< Holds the first display list id

        //The init function will create a font of
        //of the height h from the file fname.
        void init(const char * fname, unsigned int h);

        //Free all the resources assosiated with the font.
        void clean();
    };

    //The flagship function of the library - this thing will print
    //out text at window coordinates x,y, using the font ft_font.
    //The current modelview matrix will also be applied to the text. 
    void print(const font_data &ft_font, float x, float y, const char *fmt) ;

}

#endif
```

CE_Text.cpp (my problem is at void font_data::init):

```
#include <Common/Headers.h>

using namespace freetype;

namespace freetype {

    ///This function gets the first power of 2 >= the
    ///int that we pass it.
    inline int next_p2 ( int a )
    {
        int rval=1;
        while(rval<a) rval<<=1;
        return rval;
    }

    ///Create a display list coresponding to the give character.
    void make_dlist ( FT_Face face, char ch, GLuint list_base, GLuint * tex_base ) {

        //The first thing we do is get FreeType to render our character
        //into a bitmap.  This actually requires a couple of FreeType commands:

        //Load the Glyph for our character.
        if(FT_Load_Glyph( face, FT_Get_Char_Index( face, ch ), FT_LOAD_DEFAULT ))
            throw std::runtime_error("FT_Load_Glyph failed");

        //Move the face's glyph into a Glyph object.
        FT_Glyph glyph;
        if(FT_Get_Glyph( face->glyph, &glyph ))
            throw std::runtime_error("FT_Get_Glyph failed");

        //Convert the glyph to a bitmap.
        FT_Glyph_To_Bitmap( &glyph, ft_render_mode_normal, 0, 1 );
        FT_BitmapGlyph bitmap_glyph = (FT_BitmapGlyph)glyph;

        //This reference will make accessing the bitmap easier
        FT_Bitmap& bitmap=bitmap_glyph->bitmap;

        //Use our helper function to get the widths of
        //the bitmap data that we will need in order to create
        //our texture.
        int width = next_p2( bitmap.width );
        int height = next_p2( bitmap.rows );

        //Allocate memory for the texture data.
        GLubyte* expanded_data = new GLubyte[ 2 * width * height];

        //Here we fill in the data for the expanded bitmap.
        //Notice that we are using two channel bitmap (one for
        //luminocity and one for alpha), but we assign
        //both luminocity and alpha to the value that we
        //find in the FreeType bitmap. 
        //We use the ?: operator so that value which we use
        //will be 0 if we are in the padding zone, and whatever
        //is the the Freetype bitmap otherwise.
        for(int j=0; j <height;j++) {
            for(int i=0; i < width; i++){
                expanded_data[2*(i+j*width)]= expanded_data[2*(i+j*width)+1] = 
                    (i>=bitmap.width || j>=bitmap.rows) ?
                    0 : bitmap.buffer[i + bitmap.width*j];
            }
        }


        //Now we just setup some texture paramaters.
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_base[ch]);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);

        //Here we actually create the texture itself, notice
        //that we are using GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA to indicate that
        //we are using 2 channel data.
        glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height,
              0, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, expanded_data );

        //With the texture created, we don't need to expanded data anymore
        delete [] expanded_data;

        //So now we can create the display list
        glNewList(list_base+ch,GL_COMPILE);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,tex_base[ch]);

        glPushMatrix();

        //first we need to move over a little so that
        //the character has the right amount of space
        //between it and the one before it.
        glTranslatef(bitmap_glyph->left,0,0);

        //Now we move down a little in the case that the
        //bitmap extends past the bottom of the line 
        //(this is only true for characters like 'g' or 'y'.
        glTranslatef(0,bitmap_glyph->top-bitmap.rows,0);

        //Now we need to account for the fact that many of
        //our textures are filled with empty padding space.
        //We figure what portion of the texture is used by 
        //the actual character and store that information in 
        //the x and y variables, then when we draw the
        //quad, we will only reference the parts of the texture
        //that we contain the character itself.
        float   x=(float)bitmap.width / (float)width,
                y=(float)bitmap.rows / (float)height;

        //Here we draw the texturemaped quads.
        //The bitmap that we got from FreeType was not 
        //oriented quite like we would like it to be,
        //so we need to link the texture to the quad
        //so that the result will be properly aligned.
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2d(0,0); glVertex2f(0,bitmap.rows);
        glTexCoord2d(0,y); glVertex2f(0,0);
        glTexCoord2d(x,y); glVertex2f(bitmap.width,0);
        glTexCoord2d(x,0); glVertex2f(bitmap.width,bitmap.rows);
        glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();
        glTranslatef(face->glyph->advance.x >> 6 ,0,0);


        //increment the raster position as if we were a bitmap font.
        //(only needed if you want to calculate text length)
        //glBitmap(0,0,0,0,face->glyph->advance.x >> 6,0,NULL);

        //Finnish the display list
        glEndList();
    }


    void font_data::init(const char * fname, unsigned int h) {
        //Allocate some memory to store the texture ids.
        textures = new GLuint[128];

        this->h=h;

        //Create and initilize a freetype font library.
        FT_Library library;
        if (FT_Init_FreeType( &library )) 
            throw std::runtime_error("FT_Init_FreeType failed");

        //The object in which Freetype holds information on a given
        //font is called a "face".
        FT_Face face;

        //This is where we load in the font information from the file.
        //Of all the places where the code might die, this is the most likely,
        //as FT_New_Face will die if the font file does not exist or is somehow broken.
        if (FT_New_Face( library, fname, 0, &face )) 
            throw std::runtime_error("FT_New_Face failed (there is probably a problem with your font file)");

        //For some twisted reason, Freetype measures font size
        //in terms of 1/64ths of pixels.  Thus, to make a font
        //h pixels high, we need to request a size of h*64.
        //(h << 6 is just a prettier way of writting h*64)
        FT_Set_Char_Size( face, h << 6, h << 6, 96, 96);

        //Here we ask opengl to allocate resources for
        //all the textures and displays lists which we
        //are about to create.  
        list_base=glGenLists(128);
        glGenTextures( 128, textures );

        //This is where we actually create each of the fonts display lists.
        for(unsigned char i=0;i<128;i++)
            make_dlist(face,i,list_base,textures);

        //We don't need the face information now that the display
        //lists have been created, so we free the assosiated resources.
        FT_Done_Face(face);

        //Ditto for the library.
        FT_Done_FreeType(library);
    }

    void font_data::clean() {
        glDeleteLists(list_base,128);
        glDeleteTextures(128,textures);
        delete [] textures;
    }

    /// A fairly straight forward function that pushes
    /// a projection matrix that will make object world 
    /// coordinates identical to window coordinates.
    inline void pushScreenCoordinateMatrix() {
        glPushAttrib(GL_TRANSFORM_BIT);
        GLint   viewport[4];
        glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glPushMatrix();
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluOrtho2D(viewport[0],viewport[2],viewport[1],viewport[3]);
        glPopAttrib();
    }

    /// Pops the projection matrix without changing the current
    /// MatrixMode.
    inline void pop_projection_matrix() {
        glPushAttrib(GL_TRANSFORM_BIT);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glPopMatrix();
        glPopAttrib();
    }

    ///Much like Nehe's glPrint function, but modified to work
    ///with freetype fonts.
    void print(const font_data &ft_font, float x, float y, const char *fmt, ...)  {

        // We want a coordinate system where things coresponding to window pixels.
        pushScreenCoordinateMatrix();                   

        GLuint font=ft_font.list_base;
        float h=ft_font.h/.63f;                     //We make the height about 1.5* that of

        char        text[256];                              // Holds Our String
        va_list     ap;                                     // Pointer To List Of Arguments

        if (fmt == NULL)                                    // If There's No Text
            *text=0;                                            // Do Nothing

        else {
        va_start(ap, fmt);                                  // Parses The String For Variables
            vsprintf(text, fmt, ap);                        // And Converts Symbols To Actual Numbers
        va_end(ap);                                         // Results Are Stored In Text
        }


        //Here is some code to split the text that we have been
        //given into a set of lines.  
        //This could be made much neater by using
        //a regular expression library such as the one avliable from
        //boost.org (I've only done it out by hand to avoid complicating
        //this tutorial with unnecessary library dependencies).
        const char *start_line=text;
        vector<string> lines;
        for(const char *c=text;*c;c++) {
            if(*c=='\n') {
                string line;
                for(const char *n=start_line;n<c;n++) line.append(1,*n);
                lines.push_back(line);
                start_line=c+1;
            }
        }
        if(start_line) {
            string line;
            for(const char *n=start_line;n<c;n++) line.append(1,*n);
            lines.push_back(line);
        }

        glPushAttrib(GL_LIST_BIT | GL_CURRENT_BIT  | GL_ENABLE_BIT | GL_TRANSFORM_BIT); 
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);  

        glListBase(font);

        float modelview_matrix[16]; 
        glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview_matrix);

        //This is where the text display actually happens.
        //For each line of text we reset the modelview matrix
        //so that the line's text will start in the correct position.
        //Notice that we need to reset the matrix, rather than just translating
        //down by h. This is because when each character is
        //draw it modifies the current matrix so that the next character
        //will be drawn immediatly after it.  
        for(int i=0;i<lines.size();i++) {


            glPushMatrix();
            glLoadIdentity();
            glTranslatef(x,y-h*i,0);
            glMultMatrixf(modelview_matrix);

        //  The commented out raster position stuff can be useful if you need to
        //  know the length of the text that you are creating.
        //  If you decide to use it make sure to also uncomment the glBitmap command
        //  in make_dlist().
        //  glRasterPos2f(0,0);
            glCallLists(lines[i].length(), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, lines[i].c_str());
        //  float rpos[4];
        //  glGetFloatv(GL_CURRENT_RASTER_POSITION ,rpos);
        //  float len=x-rpos[0];

            glPopMatrix();



        }


        glPopAttrib();      

        pop_projection_matrix();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include `CE_Text.h` into `CE_Text.cpp` for that to work. Without seeing the definition for `font_data` class, the compiler will not allow you to define its members.

That's what it is telling you by "not recognizing `font_data` as a struct". Of course, it is not recognizing it, since it is completely unknown in `CE_Text.cpp`.

---

According to your comments, you included your header files in circular fashion. This is your problem right there. Never include header files circularly. Granted, your include guards make sure that the inclusion cycle gets broken in some way. But that does not in any way help your code to compile, as you can see in your example.

Until you completely remove any inclusion cycles from your code, trying to fix it is a crapshoot.

Comment: Headers.h includes CE_Text.h

Comment: @Tetramputechture: What??? I see that you are including `Headers.h` into `CE_Text.h` and at the same time you are including `CE_Text.h` into `Headers.h`??? This is completely useless. You cannot include headers in circular manner. This is actually something you have to watch for very carefully: never ever include headers in circular fashion. It never achieves anything except for ridiculous problems.

Comment: @Tetramputechture: This is asked awfully often these days. This is the reason for your problem. Include guards in your headers cause some header inclusions to get ignored. This is what happened in your case. And this is what causes your error. Get rid of circular inclusions immediately, and proceed from there.

Answer (score 4):

```
struct freetype::font_data{
```

should be

```
struct font_data{
```

The fact that `font_data` is in namespace `freetype` is already covered by the surrounding `namespace freetype { }`.

So, in fact, in your code it is *true* that you never did declare any `freetype::font_data` type! It's as if you were attempting to declare a `freetype::freetype::font_data` type instead.

---

This is analagous to how you do not write:

```
struct T
{
    void T::foo();
};
```

but instead:

```
struct T
{
    void foo();
};
```

Comment: Woops, that was left over code, I guess, from when I was trying to fix it. That still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: This isn't http://debug-my-code-for-me.com. With the information I've provided you are one step closer and you should now be able to debug the problem for yourself.